# Autocomplete and Fuzzy search across multiple indecies in Elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, autocomplete, fuzzy-search

I have multiple indices populated in my elasticsearch engine. And I have one text search box which is supposed to query all indices for possible hits. I am planning to query these indices fuzzy and autocomplete. Any suggestion on how the implementation should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either [`GET /_all/_search` endpoint](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-search.html#search-multi-index-type) or [create an alias](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) that gathers under it all the indices you want and use `GET /[alias_name]/_search`.

As to which field to search, I think [`_all` field could be a good match](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html), depending on how you have your mappings configured (disabling _all or not).